# Moving tables with spatial data from SQL Server to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql-server

I need to move tables with spatial data from SQL Server running on a server to PostGIS on another server daily.

My current method is using geopandas to read the tables then writing the tables to PostGIS with geopandas.to_postgis().
This method takes a lot of time for tables with big number of rows, target is to speed up this process.

How can I automate migration of spatial tables from SQL Server to PostGIS in less time?

Comment: Have you looked into the https://www.babelfishpg.org/ project? more details https://babelfishpg.org/blog/releases/2021/10/babelfish-launch/

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to state how long the process takes in seconds/minutes. You can always move just changes (the detection of which requires a duplicate copy of the data). I've usually been able to do INSERT/UPDATE/DELETEs in seconds/minutes where a full table replacement would cost hours/days.